# Find related entries with the same tags

Tags: relations, tags

I would like to retrieve related entries that have the same tags, not just one similar tag, but all of them.

At the moment I do something like:

```
{% set tags = entry.tagActualite %}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tags).id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(5).find() %}

{% if relatedEntries | length %}
    {% for entry in relatedEntries %}
        do stuff
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But it retrieves any entry with at least one similar tag.

How would i check against ALL tags ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to look at using the following syntax:

```
craft.entries.relatedTo('and', { targetElement: tags })
```

You might have some luck using the [Similar](https://github.com/aelvan/Similar-Craft) plugin.